# Can't install Python Modules

Tags: macos, terminal, python

I'm running OSX 10.8.5 with python 2.7.10. When I run the following `pip install pyodbc` I get the following error message.

Error Message:

> Command "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/private/var/folders/vy/13xnp2r52ls80mzhmcns__bm0000gp/T/pip-build-OUZxeg/pyodbc/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /var/folders/vy/13xnp2r52ls80mzhmcns__bm0000gp/T/pip-BhOEZo-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/vy/13xnp2r52ls80mzhmcns__bm0000gp/T/pip-build-OUZxeg/pyodbc

Xcode 5.1 is installed and `pip list` shows:

```
argh (0.26.1) 
html5lib (0.999999) 
pathtools (0.1.2) 
pip (7.1.0) 
PyYAML (3.11) 
setuptools (15.2) 
simplejson (3.8.0) 
six (1.9.0) 
wheel (0.24.0)
```

I'm pretty new to OS X so any help is welcome.

Comment: Have you installed Xcode ?

Comment: Could you also include the output of `pip list`?

Comment: @Mark Xcode is installed 5.1

Comment: @theoden argh (0.26.1)
html5lib (0.999999)
pathtools (0.1.2)
pip (7.1.0)
PyYAML (3.11)
setuptools (15.2)
simplejson (3.8.0)
six (1.9.0)
wheel (0.24.0)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because given the answer this question will not help anyone else

Comment: @Mark Thanks for the comment. We no longer close questions simply because they are narrow. This has a specific error and is welcome on the site. We can discuss the why in more detail at [meta] - It's a +1 question IMO.

Answer (score 1):

Problem sovled

This issue was caused because I had imported a time machine back which was made using snow lepoard. Doing this had overwrote the mountain lion libraries.

I just had to reinstall mountain lion over the existing install and then xcode and homebrew and it worked fine.

Comment: I also get messed up between the "system python" and "homebrew python" - pip vs easy_install. Good thing you sorted it out +1

Comment: @bmike pip and way_install can be used with both system and home-brew and other pythons - they all need to have the correct python in the #! header

Comment: @Mark I know and I keep forgetting the paths so my pythons need some professional wrangling from time to time.  http://i.stack.imgur.com/0tfqZ.jpg